# Data truncation: '' While Inserting or Updating Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to Insert/update a string (JSON). While inserting/Updating the value I get data truncation error.

I have tried making a JSON type column and passing an JSON_OBJECT() type but that fails as well.

```
select '''[{"id":"1202","title":"Asian","notes":"","active":"1"}]''';

CREATE TABLE mktesttable (
    id int NOT NULL,
    s VARCHAR(34530) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mktesttable
select 1, '''[{"id":"1202","title":"Asian","notes":"","active":"1"}]''';

select *  from mktesttable;
```

// That Works

---

```
INSERT INTO mktesttable
SELECT 
    patient_data.id, 
    CONCAT(
        '''[{"id":"',   patient_data.race,
        '","title":"',  list_options.title, 
        '","notes":"',  list_options.notes, 
        '","active":"', list_options.active,
        '"}]'''
    ) as s
FROM 
    patient_data 
    INNER JOIN list_options 
        ON patient_data.race = list_options.id order by 1 desc
```

Yields same result (Id's and data varies) but doesn't work

[Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLHMf.png)

Comment: Off topic: Drop the bad habit of using `order by 1`  if you change the order, add or remove columns in the select you can unwilling order on the wrong column.. Very easy mistake to mis if you have queries of a couple A4's big.. Besides `ORDER BY 1` is not ANSI SQL..

Comment: I will keep that in mind (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store JSON object, you should use the `JSON` datatype instead of strings. To create a JSON object, you can use `JSON_OBJECT`.

```
CREATE TABLE mktesttable (
    id int NOT NULL,
    s JSON NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mktesttable
SELECT 
    patient_data.id, 
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'id',     patient_data.race,
        'title',  list_options.title, 
        'notes',  list_options.notes, 
        'active', list_options.active,
    )
FROM 
    patient_data 
    INNER JOIN list_options 
        ON patient_data.race = list_options.id 
ORDER BY patient_data.id desc
```

If you need a JSON array as shown in your sample data, then :

```
    JSON_ARRAY(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'id',     patient_data.race,
            'title',  list_options.title, 
            'notes',  list_options.notes, 
            'active', list_options.active,
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. (: Much appreciated